# Не идет перенаправление запроса по ajax признаку

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess, http

Есть сайт который общается с бекэндом по ajax запросам. В .htaccess идет проверка, если это ajax запрос то перенаправляет на api.php, если нет, то index.html. Так же все запросы оформлены в REST стиле через единую точку входа.
На некоторых серверах запросы странно себя ведут, иногда в ответе приходит корректный json с бекенда, а иногда и просто index.html. Причем некоторые запросы лечатся путем добавления слеша вконце адреса: site.ru/users/2 -> site.ru/users/2/ но такой трюк не по всем адресам работает (хотя все сделано по аналогии). Для ajax запросов использую jQuery.

.htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options -Indexes
```

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

'# if it is ajax request'
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} XMLHttpRequest
RewriteRule . api.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html
    
Я в конфигурации серверов не мастер, собирал по кусочкам в интернете.

Пример удачного запроса
[image: Удачный запрос]

Пример неудачного запроса
[image: Неудачный запрос]

Подскажите в чем может быть причина такого поведения?
Спасибо.